# Looking for a WPF ComboBox with checkboxes

Tags: wpf, combobox, checkedlistbox

My google skills fail me.  Anyone heard of a control like that for WPF.  I am trying to make it look like this (winforms screenshot).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can do this yourself by setting the DataTemplate of the combo box. [This article](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-3-WPF__The_DataTemplate,_choosing_how_your_data_will_look_like.aspx) shows you how - for a listbox, but the principle is the same.

---

Another article [here](http://geeks.netindonesia.net/blogs/mahara/archive/2008/12/10/a-simple-multicolumn-combo-box-in-wpf.aspx) is perhaps a better fit for what you are trying to do, simple set the first column of the item template to be a checkbox and bind it to a bool on your business object.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                       Width="20" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DayOfWeek}"
                       Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What if you want to create a re-usable control and you don't want to add IsSelected to your business objects?

Comment: You could create a new custom control that inherits from Combobox and alter the control's template to replace the control that sits in the popup with a list including the checkboxes. Listen to the checkboxes Checked event in the control and maintain a list of checked items which you can expose through a property.

Comment: It should be <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Width="20" />, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yep, should be IsChecked. Checked is an event.

Comment: @Philippe, alimbada - Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @MartinHarris all those links are broken

Answer (score 24):

There is my combobox. I use Martin Harris code and code from this link [Can a WPF ComboBox display alternative text when its selection is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901536/can-a-wpf-combobox-display-alternative-text-when-its-selection-is-null)

```
<ComboBox Name="cbObjects" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,6,0" SelectionChanged="OnCbObjectsSelectionChanged" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectData}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Name="tbObjects" Text="Выберите объекты..." Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,2,6,0" />
```

Small class for datasource:

```
public class SelectableObject <T> {
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public T ObjectData { get; set; }

    public SelectableObject(T objectData) {
        ObjectData = objectData;
    }

    public SelectableObject(T objectData, bool isSelected) {
        IsSelected = isSelected;
        ObjectData = objectData;
    }
}
```

And there is two handler - one for handling CheckBox clicked and one for forming Text for ComboBox.

```
private void OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (SelectableObject<tblObject> cbObject in cbObjects.Items) 
    {
        if (cbObject.IsSelected)
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", cbObject.ObjectData.Description);
    }
    tbObjects.Text = sb.ToString().Trim().TrimEnd(',');
}

private void OnCbObjectsSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    comboBox.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

For ComboBox.ItemsSource I use

```
ObservableCollection<SelectableObject<tblObject>>
```

where tblObject is type of my object, a list of which I want to display in ComboBox.

I hope this code is useful to someone!

Comment: I liked the idea of SelectableObject. +1!

Comment: imho StackPanel and TextBlock in template are redundant, could just bind Content property of checkbox to ObjectData..

Comment: This solution works remarkably well despite being a bit kludgey (it requires two different, stacked controls).  The accepted answer only gets you started and is incomplete.  Other solutions involve modifying the ComboBox's template or creating custom controls and are far more complex.

Comment: Please Explain How to add value in ObservableCollection<SelectableObject<tblObject>>  as generic .

Comment: If you're binding any property of your object then the binding expression must be `{Binding ObjectData.PropertyName}`

Answer (score 11):

Give a try to [CheckComboBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckComboBox) from [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit).
The main advantage for me is having two lists for binding:

- all items available for selection
- just selected items

I find this approach more practical. In addition you can specify `value` and `display` members of the collections you're binding.

If you don't want to bring a bunch of other controls with `CheckComboBox`, you can get the [source code](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/CheckComboBox/Implementation/CheckComboBox.cs) of it, it's pretty straightforward (need to bring [Selector class](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/Primitives/Selector.cs) as well).

Answer (score 7):

ComboBox with Checkboxes

```
<ComboBox Height="16" Width="15">
    <CheckBox Content="First Checkbox" />
    <CheckBox Content="Second Checkbox" />
    <CheckBox Content="Third Checkbox" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" />
</ComboBox>
```

The provided answers surprisingly didn't work for me, I tried many variations and kept getting error messages about the checkbox not being part of combobox and the data context seemed to be broken.

In the end I didn't have to do anything involving data templates or any code behind and my bindings are working fine (not shown in example)

[image: ComboBox with Checkboxes]

I must say I'm happy with how easy this turned out to be after reading all the answers.