# WPF User Controls vs Custom Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I am trying to creating a combobox with checkboxes on each line to allow multiple selecting.  Would this be better as a User Control or Custom Control?

I haven't created a control before so just looking for a little advice on what direction I need to head.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say use a datatemplate.

Like this: [Looking for a WPF ComboBox with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859227/looking-for-a-wpf-combobox-with-checkboxes)

It's a lot more simple than trying to create your own control. :)

Comment: This answers the body of the question but not the title of the question. I came here by searching for the title.

Answer (score 67):

**UserControl (Composition)**

- Composes multiple existing controls into a reusable "group"
- Consists of a XAML and a code behind file
- Cannot be styled/templated
- Derives from UserControl

**CustomControl (Extending an existing control)**

- Extends an existing control with additional features
- Consists of a code file and a default style in Themes/Generic.xaml
- Can be styled/templated
- The best approach to build a control library

In your case, I think `UserControl` would be better; here's an example for you:

```xml
<CheckBox Content="Property" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" />
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use simple formatting or take a good look at Markup help (on the right when you Edit).