# WPF User Control with children tags

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I want to know if it is possible to make a WPF UserControl and having sub/children UserControls or not?
And If it's possible what would be the best approach to do so or where shall I start.

For example:

```
<CustomMenu>
     <CustomMenuItem x:Name="menuItem1" />
     <CustomMenuItem x:Name="menuItem2" />
     ....
</CustomMenu>
```

What is in my mind is to have that `UserControl` take some information and properties and its children have other properties which identifies them.

I've tried to make a variable in the parent UserControl such as `UIElementCollection` and represented in the `XAML file` as `StackPanel` but that wasn't exactly what I wanted specially it allowed to have other children from a different type and I couldn't set any properties for the parent `UserControl` such as the width

I'm still beginner in the WPF, so I know I must miss and don't know a lot of stuff so bear me please.

I appreciate all the help or guidance.
Thank you.

**Edit:**

After applying the solution of @Dennis (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21373956/3157993) which worked perfectly, I've noticed that a strange behavior, that if I've another instance of that UserControl in another Window or Page it will accumulate the items of the first menu, in the second one. For example: if I have a menu in the home, and another one in other page, when I open the Home, it will appear perfectly, but if I opened the other page I will have the items of the menu in the first page alongside by the items of the menu in the second page. –  Nirvana Priest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is possible to make a WPF UserControl and having sub/children
>   UserControls or not?

Yes, it is possible. Maybe, short sample will be helpful.
Parent control (XAML):

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.CustomMenu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Parent control (code-behind):

```
public partial class CustomMenu : UserControl
{
    public CustomMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomMenuItem> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<CustomMenuItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Items", 
        typeof(ObservableCollection<CustomMenuItem>), 
        typeof(CustomMenu), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<CustomMenuItem>()));
}
```

Child control (XAML):

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.CustomMenuItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, world!"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Usage:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:CustomMenu>
            <local:CustomMenu.Items>
                <local:CustomMenuItem />
                <local:CustomMenuItem />
                <local:CustomMenuItem />
            </local:CustomMenu.Items>
        </local:CustomMenu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But it isn't clear, what are you trying to achieve. Perhaps, you need a [custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6280132/580053), inherited from [HeaderedItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for that example. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a menu and its menu sub items (which I've already made that control). I'm going to check if it's best to make a Custom Control not User Control. Once again thanks. I'm going to implement it that way or using the CustomControl suggestion.

Comment: I have noticed a strange behavior, that if I've another instance of that `UserControl` in another `Window` or `Page` it will accumulate the items of the first menu, in the second one. For example: if I have a menu in the home, and another one in other page, when I open the Home, it will appear perfectly, but if I opened the other page I will have the items of the menu in the first page alongside by the items of the menu in the second page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a control by extends `System.Windows.Controls.Panel` class:

[`MSDN: Panel Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=7vRsVoIaLIH)

The sample code can be download on:

[`Create a Custom Content-Wrapping Panel Sample`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=159979)

Comment: Thanks for the link gonna check that. I do prefer to get it done through UserControl or CustomControl. But I'm giving it a shot hopefully.