# wpf map checkboxes to list items

Tags: wpf, checkbox, binding

i have a grid with checkboxes and textboxes, a list **list1 as list(of Stuff)** fills up the textboxes. **prop1** is a property of **Stuff**

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">  
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Grid Name="g1">  
         <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
         <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding prop1}" />
       </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

How can i use the checkboxes to make a new list of only the checked values?

EDIT: Fixed XAML(2)

Comment: Your XAML isn't valid. You can't have a `DataTemplate` in a `Grid` like that.

Comment: similar question as  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859227/looking-for-a-wpf-combobox-with-checkboxes  i added another property isSelected to Stuff to handle its selected(ness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wrapper class around `Stuff` that adds a boolean `IsChecked` property. Bind the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property to `StuffWrapper.IsChecked`, and bind your `TextBox.Text` property to `StuffWrapper.Stuff`. Instead of storing your `ItemsSource` as `List<Stuff>`, it is now `List<StuffWrapper>`.

Then, to make a new list of only the checked items, use the Linq "Where" function as follows:

`var checkedList = list1.Where(s => s.IsChecked);`

Comment: pretty much what i did, i posted the link to the answer in the comments. I can't answer my own posts for 8hrs coz im new.

Comment: Oh, didn't see you in the comments. Cheers!