# MVVM WPF ComboBox with CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox, combobox

I've tried to search for this for quite some time and haven't found results that help.
(perhaps my google-foo needs work?)
I'm also fairly new to WPF MVVM, so there is a lot I'm still learning.

My Question is actually in two parts...
Firstly, I have a Combobox that has Checkboxes within them within a View.
Code:

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                      Margin="15,0,0,0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding StaffNames}" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedStaffNames}"
          Grid.Row="4">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=FullName}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}},     Path=IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
                            Path=DataContext.CheckBoxSelected}"
                                  Margin="3">  
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Everytime I check a checkbox, it seems that the checkboxes get automatically unchecked.

My ViewModel code is as follows.

```
private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _isSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
```

What is wrong here?

My second question is:
Once the above is resolved, I need to append all checked names (staff names in this case) to a list and pass the values back to a separate view/view model.

I'm at a complete loss for how to accomplish this.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why have you specified the `RelativeSource`? The `DataContext` is passed to every child. Are there any binding errors on the output?

Comment: So far no binding errors.
The RelativeSource was added as an "afterthought" to attempt to get the values passed to the ViewModel... This didn't seem to work. It seems to produce the same thing with or without the Command entry

Comment: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}},     Path=IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}` so IsChecked is true only when the ComboBoxItem is selected?  That makes no sense.  I think your design for the control is a bit wonky.  Sounds like you should be using a ListBox with checks bound to your Models.

Comment: I'm sort of limited on space for this particular window.
A Combobox seemed to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

2 things that could be going wrong

1. Are you trying to set the check box value in your command - "DataContext.CheckBoxSelected"? Since you already have a binding, this could be resetting the value.
2. Clicking the checkbox does not update selected item in combo box but only updates the checkbox.

Comment: Alright, So I've changed the Checkbox to:
IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"

The "Content" of the Checkbox contains the value... should this be done differently?

Comment: Well, we should consider this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859227/looking-for-a-wpf-combobox-with-checkboxes

Comment: wait... how is that a duplicate?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? You want a checkbox within the combo box with binding. Thats what the other post talks about.

Comment: I already have it binding. what I'm looking for is how to retrieve the data of the content (or text) of the checkbox so that it can be passed to a different view model.

Comment: That would be your (comboBoxName.SelectedValue as YourViewModel).FullName