# Reset binding in code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm writing an application that is able to switch language using [this](http://codinginfinity.me/post/2015-05-10/localization_of_a_wpf_app_the_simple_approach). 
I also have a combox with two features:

- supply help text if no item is selected in combobox (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf))
- items are selectable with checkboxes (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859227/looking-for-a-wpf-combobox-with-checkboxes))

My combobox looks like

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="MyCB" SelectionChanged="OnCbObjectsSelectionChanged" ...>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked"  Width="20" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyCB, Converter={StaticResource Null2Vis}}"
        IsHitTestVisible="False"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Name="tbObjects"
        Text="{ns:Loc Var1}"
        FontSize="20"
        Foreground="Gray"/>
    </Grid>
```

I temporary deactivated the converter with `return Visibility.Visible;` with no effect.

Whenever I check some checkboxes the combobox.Text property is set and the binding from ns:Loc is overriden. How can I set it again in code if all checkboxes are unchecked?

```
private void OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var cbObject in MyCB.Items)
        if (cbObject.IsSelected)
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", cbObject.Value);
    tbObjects.Text = sb.ToString().Trim().TrimEnd(',');

    if (tbObjects.Text == "")
    {
        Binding myBinding = new Binding();
        myBinding.Source = TranslationSource.Instance["Var1"]; // <- this does not work :/
        myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbObjects, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);

        tbObjects.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    }
}
```

When all checkboxes are unchecked there is no text in the combobox.
What am I missing?

---

Edit: Added `TextBox` element to code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly to restore the localization binding you don't need to redefine the `Binding` - it should be sufficient to use `LocExtension` with proper argument, because it derives from `Binding`:

```
if (tbObjects.Text == "")
{
    var myBinding = new LocExtension("Var1");
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbObjects, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);

    tbObjects.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
}
```

But if for some reason you still want to redefine the `Binding`, here's what it should look like:

```
if (tbObjects.Text == "")
{
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("[Var1]");
    myBinding.Source = TranslationSource.Instance;
    myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbObjects, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);

    tbObjects.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
}
```

Note that the source for the binding is `TranslationSource.Instance`, and the path should be "[Var1]" to indicate its indexer with `"Var1"` argument.

## Side note

Since `TranslationSource.Item[string]` indexer is read-only, setting the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` is reduntant. Also, for the same reason, I'd set `Binding.Mode` to `OneWay`.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions work. The textbox stays empty after unchecking all checkboxes. Even if I set the text manually it doesn't change when I change the language.     
    tbObjects.Text = TranslationSource.Instance["Var1"];

Comment: In that case it would be useful if you included the `TextBox` in question in your code - at this moment we can only see the `ComboBox`.

Comment: I added the `TextBox`

Comment: What is `CBDefaultTarget`? And is its `SelectedItem` property `null`? Because otherwise the `TextBlock` is not visible (due to the binding on `Visibility` property).

Comment: Oh, sorry. `CBDefaultTarget`should be `MyCB`. I used simplified names for my question and overlooked that one. I temporary modified my converter and return `Visibility.Visible` without effect.