# Multi-level Combo Box in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-4.5

I would like to use Combo Box in my WinForms application to select only one option out of many. This choice affects the whole application and is pretty important, so I don't want to use Menu Strip for this. Therefore Combo Box is the obvious choice.

There is one problem though, I have a two-level hierarchy of these choices and I need to select and display options from the second level. Put simply, I would like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this or something similar easily using WinForms tools? Or some easy way to implement this? I haven't really implemented any visual controls in WinForms before and I don't want to waste a lot of time by learning how to. Thanks for any answer.

Comment: What are your objections to `MenuStrip`?  From what you've written and the image you show, it appears to be a better fit than a `ComboBox`.

Comment: I would probably use two combo boxes for what you are trying to do.
On selection change for the box, you would fill the second box with the choices appropriately. Otherwise I think you either need to create your own control or look into WPF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722700/wpf-treeview-inside-a-combobox

Comment: @adv12 I don't want to use Menu Strip for this for reasons related to GUI design. It is acceptable (let's call it plan B :-)) but I would much rather see something like Combo Box.

Comment: @DoomVroom I thought about two Combo Boxes, but that is not an ellegant solution (even using Menu Strip is more ellegant, but I'd like to avoid that either).

Comment: If Winforms controls not desired, you can use controls created by third part, or use WPF controls in the winforms

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that still needs this, you can use the [ToolStrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFZVf.jpg) with menu items to represent multilevel combo-boxes.

Attach click listeners to the ToolStripMenuItems and use OwnerItem to read the text of the parent.